# Usar AdMob ou semelhante para Windows Phone [Construct 2]?

Tags: admob, anúncio, pubcenter, construct-2

Estou usando o Construct 2 para criar jogos, depois que o Unity deu problema. Quero exportar principalmente para a plataforma da Microsoft (Windows e Windows Phone) porém estou enfrentando um problema ao monetizar jogos do Windows Phone, usei o plugin PubCenter para o Windows 8.1 Desktop (esse funcionou), mas não consegui de forma alguma fazer os anúncios aparecerem no Windows Phone, tentei com o AdMob (plugin nativo do Contruct 2) com o PubCenter, mas nada funciona, alguém poderia me ajudar?